# Multidimensional slicing array julia/python comparison

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, julia, slice

Let's say, i have an array in julia:

```
D[t, x, :, t ,x,:]
```

but since I'm fairly new to julia and python for my special mission, i don't really understand, what kind of output this array gives me.

Hence, I need to know, how to convert this stuff to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is an array slicing operator that selects all values from a given dimension.
In fact, `a[:]` is an equivalent to `a[1:end]` (that in Julia 1.5 can be also represented as `a[begin:end]`).

Your code a six dimensional array it will select for a given values of first,second, fourth and fifth dimension all values from third and sixth dimension. See the code below:

```
julia> D=reshape(1:2^6,fill(2,6)...);

julia> D[1,2,:,1,2,:]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 19  51
 23  55
```

Here is the Python equivalent of the above code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> D = np.reshape(np.arange(1,2**6+1),np.ones(6,dtype='int64')*2, order='F');
>>> D[0,1,:,0,1,:]
array([[19, 51],
       [23, 55]])
```

Note that we use `order='F'` to fill in the values in the same way Julia does and that Python is using 0-based indexing rather than 1-based indexing so we needed to subtract `1` from the indexes.

I also recommend reading on views and subarrays in Julia https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/subarrays/

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Could i ask you a few other questions, whenever i need it?